# Error: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I am using Eclipse "Indigo". I made a Java Project with the following Structure:

Hibernate  (Project Name)

src

Referenced Libraries

JRE System Libraries

employee.hbm.xml

hibernate.cfg.xml

Now when I am running my code its showing error **"/hibernate.cfg.xml not found"**

 Is there a way to set a path for hibernate configuration file??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its obviously a wrong setup. 
You can get a detailed explanations by searching in google how to setup eclipse to work with hibernate.
There are even video tutorials about this. [Like this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GINvxAaXDbY) :)

Good luck

Answer (score 5):

You must put hibernate.cfg.xml into src directory (in the same folder that your packages or class).

`src/`
`com.mypackage/myJava.java`
`com.otherPackage`
`hibernate.cfg.xml`

In addition, in eclipse you can define a resources directory, add it to the path and put there the hibernate.cfg.xml

I hope help you.
Marcos

Answer (score 0):

hibernate.cfg.xml has to be in your classpath. So create a source folder (like your src) and put it there. Like this:
1. Create a source folder named "properties"
2. Put your hibernate.cfg.xml there
3. Give `properties/hibernate.cfg.xml` address in your application.
4. If you are using this hibernate configuration file in your XML files, you have to use this address: `classpath:properties/hibernate.cfg.xml`